# Analysing an Algorithm to count the number of operations - Big O Notation

Tags: big-o

Taken from [Question 2 of the 2019 Eduqas A Level Computer Science Component 1 Exam](https://pastpapers.download.wjec.co.uk/s19-8501-01.pdf), there is one part of the mark scheme provided that I do not understand.

The following code is provided:

```
Algorithm Duplicates
i is integer
j is integer
for i = 0 to len(myArray)- 2
     for j = i + 1 to len(myArray)- 1
          if (myArray[i] = myArray[j])
              output “Duplicate found: ” , myArray[i]
          end if
     next j
next i
```

The question is:

> Evaluate the efficiency of the algorithm and, using Big O notation, determine the growth rate for the time performance.

The [mark scheme](https://pastpapers.download.wjec.co.uk/s19-A500U10-1%20EDUQAS%20A%20Level%20Comp%20Sci%20-%20Comp%201%20MS%20S19.pdf) provided is:

> 1 mark for identifying i loop will execute n times.  Accept n-1, n-2
>
> 1 mark for identifying j loop will execute n² times. Accept n²-1 but not n²-2
>
> 1 mark for correct numbers of calculations 2n² + n
>
> 1 mark for determining that the order will be dominated by n²
>
> 1 mark for determining that the growth rate for time performance is O(n²)

I understand why it is O(n²), due to the nested loop.
Otherwise, I have a few questions:

1. Would the inner loop not iterate ½n(n-1) times?  As it follows the triangular number sequence.
2. Why is the correct number of calculations 2n² + n?  I was under the impression that the if statement would be all considered O(1) time.
   I would make the correct number of calculations ½n(n-1) or ½n² - ½n.

I have contacted the exam board but their guidance was muddled and did not address my questions.

Any guidance would be appreciated.